# WAN Passthrough through Managed Switch

Tags: networking, security, switch, vlan

Due to physical constraints of my house is setup, I was wondering if the following would be possible/a good idea security wise.

- The fiber endpoint from my ISP terminates at their own provided GPON, which is a terrible GPON/router combo
- I want to replace this with a Ubiquiti Fiber Loco and a OPNsense installation
- I have the PoE enabled TL-SG1016PE switch

**QUESTION**: Would i be able to securely use a switch-configured VLAN (MTU, Port Based, 802.1Q or PVID) to isolate the cable/connection that comes from the Fiber Loco to the OPNsense WAN port through the use of specific ports in the switch?

This way i could power the Loco by POE and not have to deal with extra electricity cables.